# Azure website with windows authentication

Tags: azure-web-app-service, windows-authentication

I have created an application which is having Windows authentication with my office/domain action directory. Now I want to move the application Azure, not sure how the authentication will work then or what changes will be required.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a Azure Active Directory (AAD), sync it with local AD and set up ADFS. Secure the application in Azure using the synced AAD.